# jQuery change event not firing on next page of debatable

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have datatable with 60 pages each page i displayed 50 rows. I used change jQuery event with checkbox for saving record to database, event was firing on first page but from next page event not firing any more. Can any one please help me to solve this problem.

Here is my code:

```
$('input[name=child]').change(function () {

            var businessActivityId = $(this).attr("value");

            var clientId = 2;
            var isActive = $(this).is(":checked");

                $.ajax({
                    url: ROOT + 'Client/UpdateBusinessActivity',
                    data: { clientId: clientId, isActive: isActive, businessActivityId: businessActivityId},
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function () {
                     // Just saving i don't need to do anything

                    },
                    error: function (res) {


                    }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're changing pages using ajax to load the next page on your datatable, you have to bind your event using [`$(document).on('change','input[name=child]',function(){})`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind your event, since you're updating the dom dynamically.

```
// Use jQuery.on
$(document).on('change', 'input[name=child]', function () {
    var businessActivityId = $(this).attr("value");

    var clientId = 2;
    var isActive = $(this).is(":checked");

    $.ajax({
        url: ROOT + 'Client/UpdateBusinessActivity',
        data: { clientId: clientId, isActive: isActive, businessActivityId: businessActivityId},
        type: 'POST',
        success: function () {
             // Just saving i don't need to do anything

        },
        error: function (res) {

        }
    });
});
```